# SBT task to copy property file from project folder to webapp

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm new to scala and Sbt. I am trying to implement internationalization using JQuery i18n plugIn. 
My project folder structure contains messages.properties file in /src/main/resources/i18n folder which will be copied to classes folder during sbt compile/package. Jquery can access only if the file is under webapp folder. Is there a way to create a task in build.sbt to copy property file from src/main/resources folder to webapp folder.

Comment: refer to this similar question for solution
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237174/how-to-copy-some-files-to-the-build-target-directory-with-sbt)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing that, have you tried using a /classpath URL to load your properties for the jQuery plugin?